# How to 'AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.common' has no attribute '_dict_keys_to_ordered_list''

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error: module 'pandas.core.common' has no attribute '_dict_keys_to_ordered_list'

Hi, I think there is some problems in my pandas, which never happened before. I reinstalled it but did not fix it up...is there anyone who knows how to solve it? Thx!I attach all my code below, and think it is probably an environment problem in my Python (3.0 version)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import statsmodels.api as sm #Method1
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf #Method2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import requests        #get requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_onepage(url):
    strhtml=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(strhtml.text,'lxml')
    #data = soup.select('#main>div>div.mtop.firstMod.clearfix>div.centerBox>ul.newsList>li>a')
    journal = soup.select('div.sc_content > div.sc_info > span:nth-of-type(2) > a')
    citecount = soup.select('div.sc_content > div.sc_info > span:nth-of-type(3) > a')
    titlename = soup.select(' div.sc_content > h3 > a')
authorname = soup.select('div.sc_content > div.sc_info > span:nth-of-type(1)')
    yearpublish = soup.select('div.sc_content > div.sc_info > span.sc_time')
```

Comment: try turning it off and on again. . .

Comment: Well I tried but failed. At last I made it by constructing a new conda